# How to delete same data from two different database like MySQL and Neo4j in best way?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using **MySQL** and **Neo4j**. I have a Post table in MySQL and Post Node in Neo4j. What is the best way to delete post data?

** My Code is working perfectly but for fault-tolerant, I am asking this question.

One bad Use Case: When deleting I am deleting from MySQL first but when It's gone to neo4j then for some reason neo4j data not delete then it sends back an error. But my MySQL account data is already deleted but not from Neo4j. How can I make this more **fault-tolerant**? Should I make a temporary table in MySQL for this?

Comment: So dont commit the transaction on MySQL until the neo4j change is completed. If it fails Rollback the MySQL transaction. Data remains consistent. But this may be rather a pain to manage, insofar as what do you do next? How do you tell someone there is an issue somewhere so someone can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways.

**Method 1:**

Using MySQL transactions.

1. start a MySQL transaction
2. run delete query for MySQL inside the transaction
3. delete from neo4j
4. if deletion in neo4j was unsuccessful, rollback the MySQL transaction
5. if deletion in neo4j was successful, commit the MySQL transaction

This method can revert MySQL deletion if neo4j deletion was failed.
But this method can create a load on your MySQL server if too many deletions are happening at the same time. There's a certain limit on concurrent transactions.

**Method 2:**

Use the status column.

1. Delete from MySQL and mark status as `DELETING`
2. delete from neo4j
3. if deletion in neo4j was successful, change MySQL status to `DELETED`
4. if deletion in neo4j was unsuccessful, change MySQL status back to `ACTIVE`

This method can work even in a heavy load on MySQL server because of not running long transactions.
But you will have to do manual handling in this.